# Cmd: Compare two file dates

Tags: batch-file

In a cmd script (is this the same as a batch script?) I want to execute a command only if `file1` is newer than `file2`. Both files reside in the same directory.

I found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687014/how-do-i-compare-timestamps-of-files-in-a-dos-batch-script) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710671/compare-current-date-with-file-modified-date-in-batch-file) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649235/compare-2-dates-in-a-windows-batch-file) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692739/batch-to-compare-last-modify-from-two-files-in-different-folders) but none do exactly what I need, or do it in a very roundabout way or don't consider localization.

Just something like this:

```
if "%file1%" is_newer_than "%file2%" (
  execute command
)
```

- I do *not* want to find *which* file is newer.
- I do *not* want to find *the date* of the newest file.
- It must be locale-independent so no string manipulations of a formatted date allowed! (the script will be used around the globe)
- The command itself is *not* date-aware, unlike the likes of `xcopy`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738146/1052284) answer looks the most promising, but I have no idea how to use that function twice in an `if` statement.

Comment: use it twice (generating two variables), *then* do your `if`.

Comment: Your first question is asked and answered in [Windows batch files: .bat vs .cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/)

Answer (score 2):

`dir /b /a:-d /o:d /t:w %file1% %file2%` should sort files by time of write
`/o:-d` reverse sort

`for /f "tokens=*" %%? in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:d /t:w %file1% %file2%') do echo %%~tf?` example show with timestamp

Comment: Great idea for the beginning of a simple solution. But it is important to note that this only works if both files are in the same folder because a separate sort is done for each folder. I realize the OP explicitly specified this condition, but I don't want others to mistakenly use this technique for files in different folders.

Comment: One limitation - it does not tell you if two files have the exact same timestamp. I ran some quick tests, and it appears that files with identical timestamps appear in the same order if `/o-d` is used vs. `/od`. This fact could be used to identify when two files have the same timestamp.

Comment: you can make new folder with soft-link to files(or just copy) and then do above